# Jquery.each() ignores multiple commands

Tags: jquery, each

Lets say I have 50 divs ID's with

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>    and ... upto     <div id="div50"></div>
```

These divs are boxes with adequate width x height to fill a background-color.

There is another div retrieving database data as a string. It is being regex-ed to match div ID's and to fit in a jQuery selector

```
<div id="bookcaldatesci"></div>
```

The string in above div, (innerHTML) declares a set of divs. So the string (innerHTML) may look like this:

```
#div1,#div2,#div3,#div1
```

I want to change a colour of a div if that div is reffered more than one time. So div1's colour will be changed.

The problem is jquery.each() ignores the second div1 on each()

My current code is

```
$(bookcaldatesci.innerHTML).each(function(i){
    var indicator1 = $(this).css('background-color');
    if (indicator1 == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)') {
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'rgb(255, 165, 0)' });
    }
    else if (indicator1 != 'rgb(255, 165, 0)') {
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 255)';
    }
});
```

In summary if div1 is already blue, make it orange as a warning. If it's not blue make it blue.

I pinpointed the problem - I manage to return a string for .each()'s result and then understood that the second div1 is missing when it goes through .each() I'm looking for a way to avoid this. So jQuery ignores my 2nd #div1 and he runs .each() command as

```
#div1,#div2,#div3
```

dropping the last div1. This was the string returned when I tested through .each().

Is there anything I can do to not to drop the last div1?

Edit-
Question: First iteration was ran, Why run a second iteration?

Answer: If present, I need it to run a second iteration too. So if there is a second iteration I need it to change colour (so it warns me). This string comes from a database automated, regarding bookings. If there is an overlap, admin should be warned. I built the string using regex so the string is same as the list of id's so I can get it inside jQuery selector.

Comment: If present, I need it to run a second iteration too. So if there is a second iteration I need it to change colour (so it warns me). This string comes from a database automated, regarding bookings. If there is an overlap, admin should be warned. I built the string using regex so the string is same as the list of id's so I can get it inside jQuery selector.

Comment: Having 2 or more items with same id is a dom error. try using classes instead. maybe this can solve the issue

Comment: Can you post your real `html` ?

Comment: @sissy These are not two different divs. I'm calling the same ID twice.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood it :)

Comment: @RCV it's so long. Lets say I have 50 divs with IDs: div1, div2, div3 etc...  and innerHTML data I have given above in my question. Apart from that nothing much except the database info I have mentioned above in my question.

Comment: maybe passing it as a html is interpreted as an error of a repeated id. are you able to manage the returned string?you could make a try using classes...

Comment: Yes that is the issue. I manage to return a string for .each()'s result and then understood that the second div1 is missing when it goes through .each() I'm looking for a way to avoid this.

Comment: The selector you hand to `$()` represents a *set* of elements and sets don't have duplicates...

Comment: @muistooshort Is there a way to add duplicates?

Comment: I suppose you could split the string into pieces by hand and iterate over an array.

Comment: @muistooshort good idea, last resort though... I wish there was .eachwithduplicates() like function :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered through a different approach (Javascript)

```
function find_duplicates(arr) {
var len=arr.length,
  out=[],
  counts={};

for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
var item = arr[i];
var count = counts[item];
counts[item] = counts[item] >= 1 ? counts[item] + 1 : 1;
}

for (var item in counts) {
if(counts[item] > 1)
  out.push(item);
}

alert(out);
}

find_duplicates(bookcaldatesci.innerHTML.split(","));
```

Sending the alert to the jQuery selector, can obtain the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like you have a typo:

```
$(bookcaldatesci.innerHTML).each(function(i){
    var indicator1 = $(this).css('background-color');
    if (indicator1 == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)') {
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'rgb(255, 165, 0)' });
    }
    else if (indicator1 != 'rgb(255, 165, 0)') {
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 255)';
    }
});
```

Look againt at your second test: "If it's **not** orange, make it blue"

Answer (score -1):

**Ids must be unique for each element within a page.** Therefore you cannot use the same Id on two difference div's. This is what is causing your problem. if you want to make divs with the same id to group them for some reason I suggest you use a class.

Comment: These are not two different divs. I'm calling the same ID twice.

Comment: When you say the Id's are stored as a string do you mean something like <span id="bookcaldatesci">#div1,#div2,#div3,#div1</span> ?